# finding the coordinates of a point given a distance

Tags: coordinate-systems

I have a fixed point $(a,b)$ and movable point $(c,d)$. The distance between these two points is $r$. Now, I want to increase the distance to, say, $r'$. What are the new coordinates of the new point $(c',d')$ with respect to the original so that $(a,b), (c,d), (c',d')$ are collinear.

Comment: consider the circumference $C$  with center $(a,b)$ and ratii $r'$. Every point in $C$ works

Comment: sorry, edited! I wanted to say these three points are collinear.

Comment: So, two points works: the intersection of $C$ with this line

Answer (score 0):

The triplets of points $\{(a,b),(c,d),(c,a)\}$ makes a right triangle where the segment $(a,b)-(c,d)$ is the hypothenuse and has length $r$. Assuming the new point at distance $r'$ moves in the same direction as the hypothenusa, you obtain a new similar right triangle and the length of the new cathetus can be trivially found by similarity.

$$\left\{\begin{align}
\frac{c'-a}{c-a}&=\frac{r'}{r} \\
\frac{d'-b}{d-b}&=\frac{r'}{r}
\end{align}\right. $$